# looping over a vector with trycatch

Tags: r, function, loops, try-catch

I am trying to do a match over a list but i am unable to get an kind of output from my function. the loop fails at vec[3] that is why i used trycatch. but im still unable to get any matches in output of my function. i am unable to output anything. also could the same thing be done with apply family?

Im trying to match loc over vec. vec[3] will fail since there i no match.

```
vec=c('i am going to ooty corbett','i have to go to ooty', 'i have to go to manali')
loc=c('ooty','corbett')
```

out is the vector im trying to build for the matches.

```
out=NULL
res_m=function(x,y){
    out[i]=tryCatch(
        {
            for(i in 1:length(y)){
                print(i)
                x=tolower(x)
                y=strsplit(y[i], " ")[[1]]
                out[i]=intersect(x,y)
            }
        },error=function(cond) {
            out[i]=NA
        },
        finally=print("can do")
    )    
    return(out[i])
}
res=res_m(loc,vec)
```

Using ifelse, i got it to work. but still if could get a solution out of my approach.

```
res=NULL
out=NULL

for (i in 1:length(y)) {
    print(i)
    x = tolower(x)
    z = strsplit(y[i], " ")[[1]]
    out = intersect(x,z)
    if (length(out) == 0) {
        res[i] = NA
    }else{
        res[[i]] = out
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is probably because `intersect` gives a 0-length vector that is assigned to "out". So, you could handle this case with an `if/else` before assigning. Alternatively, see `grepl(paste(loc, collapse = "|"), vec)` or `regmatches(vec, gregexpr(paste(loc, collapse = "|"), vec))`

Comment: @alexis_laz: yeah the vec[3] will return null.that is why i have used trycatch. i will try it with ifelse and the other one too. but i think using set operation would be fast. so i was thinking on lines of apply family. thanks for the help.

Comment: use `if( length(...) ){ } else { }` . You have not actually said there was an error, so `tryCatch` would not seem appropriate.

Comment: okay i tried with if else too. it is not working.

Comment: @alexis_laz: grepl gives me index though i want the values. the second gives me values which is exactly what i want  and is fast too but i would still like a solution for my attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `res_m` you don't initialize "out" as an appropriate object and, also, you're overwriting "y":

```
res_m = function(x, y)
{
    out = vector("list", length(y)) 
    for(i in 1:length(y)) {
        x = tolower(x)
        yy = strsplit(y[i], " ")[[1]]
        out[[i]] = intersect(x, yy)     
    }

    return(out)
}
res_m(loc, vec)
#[[1]]
#[1] "ooty"    "corbett"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "ooty"
#
#[[3]]
#character(0)
```

You can move `tolower` and `strsplit` out of your loop:

```
res_m2 = function(x, y)
{
    out = vector("list", length(y))
    x = tolower(x)
    y = strsplit(y, " ")
    for(i in seq_along(y)) out[[i]] = intersect(x, y[[i]])
    return(out)
}
res_m2(loc, vec)
#[[1]]
#[1] "ooty"    "corbett"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "ooty"
#
#[[3]]
#character(0)
```

Or use `lapply`:

```
res_m3 = function(x, y)
{
    x = tolower(x)
    lapply(strsplit(y, " "), function(yy) intersect(x, yy))
}   
res_m3(loc, vec)
#[[1]]
#[1] "ooty"    "corbett"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "ooty"
#
#[[3]]
#character(0)
```

If you *have* to make an error:

```
force_error = function(x, y)
{
    out = vector("list", length(y))
    x = tolower(x)
    y = strsplit(y, " ")
    for(i in seq_along(y)) 
        tryCatch(expr =  { out[i] = intersect(x, y[[i]]) }, 
                 error = function(e) { 
                     cat(sprintf("error in in 'i = %d'\n    --> %s\n", i, e))
                     out[i] <<- NA
                 }, 
                 warning = function(w) {
                     cat(sprintf("warning in in 'i = %d'\n    --> %s\n", i, w))
                     out[i] <<- NA
                 })
    return(out)
}   
force_error(loc, vec)
#warning in in 'i = 1'
#    --> simpleWarning in out[i] = intersect(x, y[[i]]): number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
#
#error in in 'i = 3'
#    --> Error in out[i] = intersect(x, y[[i]]): replacement has length zero
#
#[[1]]
#[1] NA
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "ooty"
#
#[[3]]
#[1] NA
```

Alternatively, you could use

```
regmatches(vec, gregexpr(paste(loc, collapse = "|"), vec))
#[[1]]
#[1] "ooty"    "corbett"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "ooty"
#
#[[3]]
#character(0)
```

Comment: Perfect anwser! thanks!  I made a lot of silly mistakes in here. your anwser is very useful.